# How are current anonymous users calculated?

Tags: users, 6

I have a site running Drupal 6. When I log in to add new articles, it shows *Current Anonymous / Authenticated Users*.

How is this number computed?

Comment: I don't understand. Where is the number?

Comment: Hi, in the upper right hand corner in Drupal 6 (authenticated mode)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at what's written in [Comment nr 5 of issue nr 799262](https://www.drupal.org/node/799262#comment-3855280), ie:

> Basically, the anonymous user count in Drupal core's "who's online" block counts how many sessions are stored in the database, minus the number of authenticated sessions.
>
> If you haven't correctly configured PHP to periodically cleanup the active sessions, the table will continue to grow. I just cleaned one today with ~75,000 old anonymous sessions. This not only causes confusion in the who's online block, but also has a severe performance impact on your site if it's mildly busy.
>
> This article shows you what you need to put in settings.php to ensure your anonymous sessions are being cleaned: https://techcommons.stanford.edu/topics/drupal/sessions-table-cleanup

Comment: Hi so what setting in the stanford site ensures anonymous sessions are being cleaned? Thanks

Comment: @user3236765 that's another (new) question. Why not creating a new question about that? And if you want add a link to this question?